# Checking of edit mode condition on tap of another tab in tabbarcontroller in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, swift4, uitabbaritem

I am new to iOS Development.I have some requirement . I want to check the particular condition when another tab is selected.

Here is the part of UITabviewController delegate method code.

```
  func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {

    if(Constants.isEditing!>0){
        showAlert(tabBarController,viewController)
        return false
    }
        return true
```

on the above code , show alert will shown Alert dialog with `Yes` and `No` Button.
when the user tap of `yes`, user can able to switch tab.

example:

There are following tabs.

`Search`  `Message` `Profile` `Settings`

Now I am in the Profile section and editing my profile.
when I click on message or any other tab, it's gone to another tab. even though, I am editing my profile.

so, all the data I entered has lost. so, I put one static variable on UITabViewController and increasing the count when the user type something on edit profile textfield. so, in above function you see, `Constants.isEditing > 0` means, we should show alert dialog and if the user selected the `yes` button means, I set the isEditing to 0 and allow the user to go message or any other tab.

if the user selected `No` means, we let the user to be in same screen itself.

on this requirement Anyone please help me to solve this issue. ? Helps will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

So, here tabBarController function is called when i click on `settings` tab.
The actual functionality of this function is, ask the user to proceed with `settings` click. Here i said `false` to the system and showing the alert dialog.

So, it's showing the AlertDialog with `Yes`  `No` button.that is OK. But when the user select `Yes`, we cant move to `Settings` tab. because, we don't have any references that the `Settings`  tab clicked. so, it's still on that screen.

Hope the description explains clearly. Update me if i missed anything.

Comment: Can you clarify on what exactly you need help with?  I'm not quite seeing which part you're stuck on.

Comment: i am editing the some content on profile screen. when i unawarely click on message or any other tab, the edited data from profile screen all are lost. so, made some functionality, that describes how i am doing it.

Comment: The tabBarController should persist your controller though, if you're losing data when selecting a different tab I would think that you're clearing the information in your viewDidDisappear or viewDidAppear in that specific controller.

Comment: I want to show the alert if the user is editing on something on screen. How do I do that? is there any inbuilt function?

Comment: I do not believe there is anything built in specifically for what it sounds like you're trying to do.  In your `shouldSelect viewController:` function, you could store the selected index, then in the callback for your UIAlertController that you're displaying the dialog, you could programmatically set the selected tab for the tabBarController to be that selected index.